# Changing "src" of an "img" html element doesn't refresh it

Tags: jquery, html, refresh, image

I'm using

```
$("#my_img").attr("src", "/another_img.png");
```

inside the "beforeSend" callback of an Ajax request using jQuery, the problem is that the the img isn't being always refreshed to the user, sometimes I saw the new image and sometimes not, is there anyway to force the refresh of the img ? I was thinking that by changing the "src" attribute of the img element was enough to make the engine refresh the image. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like it might be a caching issue, try:

```
$("#my_img").attr("src", "/another_img.png?v=" + new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: because it adds something unique to the request. The name "v" is arbitrary.